# AWS Elastic BeanStalk with PHP 8.1

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, composer-php, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, php-8.1

Trying to upgrade elastic beanstalk to php 8.1, I need it for composer monolog and symfony. Error logs says I am on 8.0.

Inside .ebextensions/02_my_commands.config I tried to add this, and I am not getting any command errors

```
commands:
  00_upgrade_php:
    command: |
      sudo yum -y install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
      sudo yum -y install https://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
      sudo yum -y install yum-utils
      sudo yum -y install rpl
      export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
      export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
      sudo yum-config-manager --disable 'remi-php*'
      sudo yum-config-manager --enable remi-php81
      rpl [remi-php81] "[remi-php81]\npriority=1" /etc/yum.repos.d/remi-php81.repo -e
      sudo yum upgrade -y php php-*
```

However it says I am still on PHP version 8.0 and I do not understand why

Here is the error:

```
Problem 1
    - monolog/monolog is locked to version 3.0.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - monolog/monolog 3.0.0 requires php >=8.1 -> your php version (8.0.6) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - symfony/translation is locked to version v6.1.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - symfony/translation v6.1.0 requires php >=8.1 -> your php version (8.0.6) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 3
    - symfony/translation-contracts is locked to version v3.1.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - symfony/translation-contracts v3.1.0 requires php >=8.1 -> your php version (8.0.6) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 4
    - monolog/monolog 3.0.0 requires php >=8.1 -> your php version (8.0.6) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - google/apiclient v2.12.5 requires monolog/monolog ^1.17||^2.0||^3.0 -> satisfiable by monolog/monolog[3.0.0].
    - google/apiclient is locked to version v2.12.5 and an update of this package was not requested.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading the platform version may solve your issue, it should come with php8.1 already installed
[AWS PHP PLATFORMS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQUzI.png)

Comment: At the time I posted the question 8.1 was still not supported by AWS. Thanks for letting me know that it is now up!